# Passing Object Manager in view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Using ZF2 with Doctrine 2.

For the needs of the application i passed `objectmanager` as a variable (`$om`) in `return new ViewModel`

so i can use it in my view:

```
$om->getRepository('\Schema\Entity\Category')->findBy(.....
```

The thing that confuses me is:

1) Do I break MVC rules? (Because some say that is a bad practice and some others not)

2) Am I going to face any problems with the development of the application using this tactic?

Comment: This is a bad practice. It will break the MVC concept.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes you do
2. violation of coding standards always has negative side-effects

The Job of the Controller is to pass the Data you need into the View. For this Purpose the Controller interacts with the Model.

```
public function fooAction() 
{
    return new ViewModel([
        'entities' => $this->getObjectManager()->findBy([
            'foo' => 'bar'
        ])
    ]);
}
```

That's pretty much how you will do it. Next question for you **should** be: *What does `getObjectManager()` do or how do i properly inject the `ObjectManager` into the Controller?*

The answer is as simple: **You have to use Controller-Factories**

```
//module.config.php
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'YourNamespace\Controller\FooController' => function($cpm) {
            $ctrl = new FooController();
            $ctrl->setObjectManager(
                $cpm->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            );
            return $ctrl;
        }
    ]
]
```

And that's all there is to it. Now you have a very clean setup of what you want to achieve ;)